# How to properly catch the access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I can't seem to catch the access token as invalid even when i logged out of facebook.

```
    if ($user) {
          try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
 echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
          } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
            // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
            // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
            // just ask the user to login again here.
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
          }
        }
```

I am still getting the user name back even when i am logout of facebook. So apparently the access token seems still valid. How can i fix this?

Or should i test my app only in FB enviroment in an iframe?

Comment: anyone?? somehow i can't catch the exception??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token does not depend on yours auth status on Facebook. Facebook PHP SDK, that you are using, stores access token in PHP session. So, you can just clean your session.

Comment: tx Oleg for clearing that up, i will try your suggestion. Do i have to start_session? or is it part of the PHP-SDK But do you know why the default code from FB doesn't work in my cause? code is on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Comment: start_session is a part of the PHP-SDK. Default code doesn't contain valid appId and secret ;)